# Failed to launch calculator in android emulator through appium

Tags: java, android-emulator, webdriver, appium

I just create a sample code as below which is used to launch the calculator apk file and perform some task

```
@BeforeSuite
    public static void driverInitalize() throws Exception {
        try {

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.2.2");
            // capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
            capabilities
                    .setCapability("app",
                            "C:\\Ecare\\Appium\\com.android.calculator2-5.1-1720659-22-minAPI22.apk");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public static void sampleTest1() throws Exception {
        try {

            // System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'7')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'+')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'3')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'=')]")).click();
            String value = driver.findElement(
                    By.className("android.widget.EditText")).getText();
            System.out.print(value);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.quit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I executed the above code will return following exception in appium server as well as in eclipse IDE. Can somebody tell me how can I overcome this issue. It seems to be the session is progress but I'm not sure how to kill the progress session which is started earlier. I tried to start up the appium server as appium --no-reset, and checked in the override existing session as well but no luck.

```
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1358:17
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
>     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/b23beec2f0794d869eb021f75e3791bd.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK])","origValue":"Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/b23beec2f0794d869eb021f75e3791bd.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 39088.716 ms - 362
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] is caused due to the version of android of your avd/device is older than the version being used to compile the code of the app. 
Check the target sdk version and the minimum sdk version of the app.

if you have the access to the source code of the app these information will be in the manifest file in the `android:minSdkVersion` tag.